# Will variable be assigned to empty if the command for command substitution failed in shell scriping?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
a=whatever
f(){return 1}
echo $a # this gives whatever
a=$(f)
echo $a # now a is empty
```

Is this because command returned non zero, so command substitution failed, thus `a` is set to empty? Is this a well defined behavior? Can't find it anywhere. Could you point me to the doc describing it?

I tried to grep something from a file and assign the result to the variable. So I did `a=$(grep pattern file_not_exist)`. Then I see grep complained that the file does not exist. I wonder why this complaint message is not assigned to the variable rather than being printed out? Is it because of stdout and stderr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not because the command failed that `a` is empty.

The command didn't produce any output data, so there is no data to be captured in `a`.

Revise the function to read:

```
f(){ echo Hello; return 1; }
```

Now run the command substitution.  You'll find that `a` contains `Hello`.  If you check `$?` immediately after the assignment, it contains `1`, the status returned from the function.  Exit statuses and command outputs are separate.

The documentation is in the GNU Bash manual for [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: I tried to grep something from a file and assign the result to the variable. so I did `a=$(grep pattern file_not_exist)`. Then I see grep complained that the file does not exist. I wonder why this complaint message is not assigned to the variable rather than being printed out? Is it because of stdout and stderr?

Comment: In well-written commands, error messages are written to `stderr`.  Command substitution captures `stdout`.  There are questions and answers on SO about how to capture `stderr` instead of, or as well as, `stdout` — usually wanting the two in separate variables.  That gets really hairy really quickly.  But for the simple cases, you want to capture the output from `stdout`, and you still get to see any error messages.